# How to get specific culture Number pattern in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, string-formatting

I am trying to display comma after thousand ex: 1,000 but it is not working my code is below

```
string.Format("{0:#,###0.#}", s.ToString());
```

I have tried so many type as some references and suggestion that code is below

```
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N}", s.ToString());
```

in postback method I have written below code

```
CultureInfo en = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = en;
```

where I am going wrong I am not able to find please help me

**UPDATE:**

as per **@Umakant Dubey** suggestion I tried it is working when we pass static value that code is below

```
var amount = 44690.7500;
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            var formattedAmount = String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}", amount);
```

the above code is working, but when change the code means If I pass dynamic values it will not work that is below

```
var amount = dts.Rows[0][16];
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            var formattedAmount = String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}", amount);
```

Comment: What is `s` here? Please show a [mcve]. Note that passing a *string* as an argument to `string.Format` isn't going to help you format `s` as a number... (I also suggest you remove the ASP.NET tag, as this has nothing to do with ASP.NET. I would encourage you to write a console app as your example.)

Answer (score 2):

This might solve your issue

```
s.ToString("N0");
```

[image]

You need your `s` variable to be type of int or some numeric data type instead of string.

Comment: the best overloaded method match for string.tostring(system.|Format provider) has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

If `s` is a number > 1000, doesn't this just work?

```
var s = 12345;
string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), 
    "{0:#,###0.#}", s)
```

This outputs: `"12,345"`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

```
string str = String.Format("{0:n}", 1234);
string strWithoutDecimal = string.Format("{0:n0}", 1234);
string str3 = 1234.ToString("N0");
string str4 = 1234.ToString("#,##0");
string strCultureSpecific = (1234).ToString("N",new CultureInfo("en-US"));
string strNoCulture = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:N0}", 1234);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try,

```
   NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
   nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
   int myMoney = 1234;
   Console.WriteLine(myMoney.ToString("N", nfi));
```

This works for me, if you want a display decimal digits- you can also specify using NumberDecimalDigits property.